# Training an LSTM "autoencoder" without a decoder?

Tags: time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoders

Say you take a timeseries. Then you'd train the model to predict a future window, based on a previous window, i.e. learn the temporal dependence in data through forecasting. This would result in both an optimizable loss, as well as a final hidden state that describes the data.

Could this in theory work as an autoencoder? Why do you need the second LSTM to unpack the first when it's already a working system on its own?

### Edit:

It turns out that without the unpacking of the decoder, the encoder's final hidden state has no reason to summarize anything, so it just learns to return the final datapoint. This of course results in a low reconstruction error, but the latent representations are useless for anything else.

Comment: because the whole point of an autoencoder is to get a fixed-length feature vector from a variable-length input.  So, you need to reduce the sequence to a fixed-length vector (the encoding LSTM), then, since you're doing a prediction task as you've noticed, and since that is the labelled data that you have access to, you use the resulting fixed-length vector to try and reproduce the sequence (the decoding LSTM)

Comment: But what I don't understand is why I can't use the fixed-size hidden state from the forecasting model, since this must have *some* information about the data, in order to be able to forecast it. Different data will require different hidden states for reconstruction *as well as* forecasting, no?

Comment: Could be.  Generally the hidden state for RNNs is designed to forget old info, so that for a long sequence the later bits will be weighted higher in the hidden state than the earlier bits.  This may or may not be a desirable quality when vectorizing a sequence.

Comment: However, theory only gets one so far, and the best way to tell how effective an algorithm is is to science it.  [Grab some sequence data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Character+Trajectories) and try both methods.  Be sure to let us know what you find out.  :)